# Create Contentful Custom Slug

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I'm currently using the Contentful 'slug generator' widget which auto-generates a slug from the Title field. Is there a way I can automatically add a prefix to the slug? Ex:

`Current: Post Title -> post-title
What I want: Post Title -> post/post-title`

I know I can manually add post/, but I forget sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I cloned and modified the original '[slug generator](https://github.com/contentful/extensions/tree/master/samples/slug)' extension.

```
function setSlug (slug) {
    var preSlug = 'post/' + slug
    input.value = preSlug
    slugField.setValue(preSlug)
    setStatus('loading')
    debouncedUpdateStatus(preSlug)
  }
```

It's hardcoded for now, but hopefully, I'll have enough time to display an input field so I can set any prefix.